# Python. Error message on "UserWarning: Glyph 3610 (\N{THAI CHARACTER BO BAIMAI}) missing from current font."

Tags: python, plot, fonts

I'm trying to annotate on matplotlib with Thai characters. However I'm getting a series of errors below:

```
C:\Users\zongyi.ng\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17356/4111577642.py:58: UserWarning: Glyph 3610 (\N{THAI CHARACTER BO BAIMAI}) missing from current font.
  fig.savefig(country + "_top50.png")
C:\Users\zongyi.ng\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17356/4111577642.py:58: UserWarning: Glyph 3640 (\N{THAI CHARACTER SARA U}) missing from current font.
  fig.savefig(country + "_top50.png")
C:\Users\zongyi.ng\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17356/4111577642.py:58: UserWarning: Glyph 3627 (\N{THAI CHARACTER HO HIP}) missing from current font.
  fig.savefig(country + "_top50.png")
C:\Users\zongyi.ng\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17356/4111577642.py:58: UserWarning: Glyph 3619 (\N{THAI CHARACTER RO RUA}) missing from current font.
  fig.savefig(country + "_top50.png")
```

I was still able to plot but the annotation appear with "square" characters - below.
The same code was used for other country plot and appear fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
!wget -q https://github.com/google/fonts/raw/main/ofl/sarabun/Sarabun-Regular.ttf
mpl.font_manager.fontManager.addfont('Sarabun-Regular.ttf')
mpl.rc('font', family='Sarabun')
plt.rcParams ['font.family'] = ('Sarabun')
```

Or if you are using nx

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos,node_size= 2400,font_family='Sarabun')
```